# How to store data more effectively and efficiently in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am designing a project which store documents for each customer:

- There are Customers, Users, Companies and Documents.
- Each Customer has Users, Companies and Documents.

Should i create Collection for Companies and Documents and populate with Customer or store them in Customers Collection as arrays. Which way is more accurate?

**To be more enlightening:**

- ABC Accounting Office is a **Customer**.
- ABC has users and i store them in **Users** Collection with **Customer ID**.
- ABC has **Companies** and store **Documents** for each of them.

Comment: If you complete data never exceed 16MB, you can save it to 1 collection. This will avoid complex queries, like `$lookup`, etc... However, if you need to store each entity separately, it's OK. Make sure your `CustomerId`, `UserId` points `_id` field for integrity reason.

Comment: One collection can hold 16mb data? What happens if i have lots of user and it exceeds 16mb?

Comment: No. 16Mb / per document (you can hold terabyte data within a collection). If any document exceeds 16Mb during insertion / update / aggregation, MongoDB opeation will fail